# how can I get just a single div to refresh on submit as apposed to the entire page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working  with a dynamically  generated page written in PHP. The divon the page contain contents listed  FancyBox  links that open editing screens.
Once editing is complete and the user closes the FancyBox modal the changes
need to be reflected on the parent page.

Right, so I was able to find a solution that refreshes the entire page on submit
using

```
  parent.location.reload (true);
```

to refresh the entire parent page. But, that causes a browser prompt
that is confusing to users and a bit of over kill as I really only
need the information edited to refresh.

**how can I get just a single div to refresh on submit  as
apposed to the entire page??????**

Comment: You answered it in a tag: ajax.

Answer (score 3):

You need to submit the form through AJAX. Since your using something that uses jQuery, you can use it to do it.

[Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) you can find a tutorial on how to do it

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is loading page fragments with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

something like,

```
$('#pageNeedToBeRefreshed').load('test.html #pageNeedToBeRefreshed');
```

Answer (score 0):

User ,

It should be pretty easy

have a div place holder like below

```
<div id="dataToRefresh"> </div>
```

Once you close the dialog, have a event handler...

`$('dataToRefresh').html('testing');` // give your data here

it should upate the parts of the page

let me know if you need anything else

please go thruogh .html api for more info

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: in my case the edit is new page open as popup , i want to update the value in parent div?   i am using jquery fancybox for popup

Comment: @nidhinraj , even it is popup it is still avaible as a html , so you can get values from the popup and update the anywhere in the page , when you close the popup , its just hiding thats it , you can have your code in the close event of fancy box

Comment: the values am storing it in the database , i just want to display that in the div

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the below div to refresh:

Then write

```
$("#dataToRefresh").load();
```

Might it will be helping you

Comment: @Nidhiraj , .load takes arguments and load the contents to that div...see this api http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: after submitting the fancy box popup value i want to display in parent page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using submit in html you can submit your form using the ajax -

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
        var data = $(this).serialize();  //this gives you the data of all elements of form in serialized format
        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              dataType:"json",
              url: 'your url',
              data: data,
              success: function(data){

                           //replace the contents of the div you want to refresh here.
                           }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#id_of_div').load('/url/to/updated/html');
```

See [jQuery docs for load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)